# Approximating the change in a function using partial derivatives

Tags: calculus

I have the following function C(v1,v2):

[image]

I want to find the chance of C when there is a certain change in v1 and v2. So given $Δv_1,Δv_2$, what is $ΔC$?

I was given this solution:

[image]

It was explained that the change of C has to be the sum of the change in each direction (v1, v2) weighted by the derivative of C in that direction. **I don't understand why the change of C correlates to the product of the derivative of C and its sum of change in each direction?**

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_derivative

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a process that use linear function to approximate an arbitrary function.

In 1-dimensional case, we have $f(x_0+\Delta x)\approx f(x_0)+f'(x_0)\Delta x$, and the geometric meaning is using the line to approximate the function $f(x)$.

(note that $y=f(x_0)+f'(x_0)\Delta x$ is a linear function of $\Delta x$)

Thus, it's natural to use a plane to approximate a 2-variables function $C(v_1,v_2)$, that is $C(v_1+\Delta v_1,v_2+\Delta v_2)\approx C(v_1,v_2)+C_{v_1}\Delta v_1+C_{v_2}\Delta v_2$.

The geometric meaning of $z=C({v_1,v_2})+C_{v_1}\Delta v_1+C_{v_2}\Delta v_2$ is a plane which is tangent to $C(\cdot,\cdot)$ at $(v_1,v_2)$, and we use the plane to approximate $C$.

Comment: There is something nontrivial here, though, which is that we can get a good linear approximation in an arbitrary direction using just the partial derivatives, which are only known to be good approximations in two particular directions.

Comment: @EricWofsey The tangent space at a fixed point is spanned by the two partial derivatives, and they are a basis of the tangent space. So choosing other basis is okay.

Comment: I get the geometric mean in a 1-dimensional case. However, I am confused as to why $C(v_1,v_2)$, that is $C(v_1+\Delta v_1,v_2+\Delta v_2)\approx C_{v_1,v_2}+C'_{v_1}\Delta v_1+C_{v_2}\Delta v_2$. What does $C_{v_2}$ mean if it is not a derivative?

Comment: @Pablo It's a typo, sorry.

Comment: @W.mu what does $C_{v1}$ and $C_{v2}$ mean? Isn't the function C need two parameters?

Comment: $C_{v_1}$ is $\frac{\partial}{\partial v_1}C(v_1,v_2)$

Answer (score 1):

Let me write $\partial_1 C=\frac{\partial C}{\partial v_1}$ and $\partial_2 C=\frac{\partial C}{\partial v_2}$.  Then we have $$C(a+\Delta v_1,b)\approx C(a,b)+\partial_1C(a,b) \Delta v_1$$ (this is the definition of $\partial_1C(a,b)$, the rate of change of $C$ when we change the first input).  Similarly, $$C(a+\Delta v_1,b+\Delta v_2)\approx C(a+\Delta v_1,b)+\partial_2 C(a+\Delta v_1,b)\Delta v_2.$$  Moreover, assuming $\partial_2C$ is continuous, $\partial_2C(a+\Delta v_1,b)\approx \partial_2 C(a,b)$.  So we get $$C(a+\Delta v_1,b+\Delta v_2)\approx C(a+\Delta v_1,b)+\partial_2 C(a,b)\Delta v_2\approx C(a,b)+\partial_1C(a,b) \Delta v_1+\partial_2 C(a,b)\Delta v_2.$$
Or, if $\Delta C$ stands for $C(a+\Delta v_1,b+\Delta v_2)-C(a,b)$, $$\Delta C\approx \partial_1C(a,b) \Delta v_1+\partial_2 C(a,b)\Delta v_2.$$

More briefly: we can get from $(a,b)$ to $(a+\Delta v_1,b+\Delta v_2)$ by first taking a step of $\Delta v_1$ in the $v_1$-direction and then taking a step of $\Delta v_2$ in the $v_2$-direction.  The first step changes $C$ by about $\frac{\partial C}{\partial v_1}\Delta v_1$ and the second step changes $C$ by about $\frac{\partial C}{\partial v_2}\Delta v_2$, so the total change is about their sum.

Comment: I lost you at $\partial_2C$ is continuous, $\partial_2C(a+\Delta v_1,b)\approx \partial_2 C(a,b)$. Why can that be assumed? Also, is there a name to this principle so I can do further research on my own?

Comment: Well, the result is not true in general if $\partial_2 C$ is not continuous.  I don't know a name for this, but some related concepts you can look up are "directional derivative", "gradient", and "total derivative".